# Python regex to check if a string has particular set of numbers

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if this set of number appears in a string in an exact pattern or not:

**String I want to check:** `\4&2096297&0`

**My code**

```
a = "SCSI\DISK&VEN_MICRON&PROD_1100\4&2096297&0&000200"
print(bool(re.match(r"\4&2096297&0+", a)))
```

It returns False instead of true. If I try same thing on `print(bool(re.match(r"hello[0-9]+", 'hello1')))`. I get true. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How about `a = "SCSI\DISK&VEN_MICRON&PROD_1100\4&2096297&0&000200"
print("\4&2096297&0" in a)`

Comment: I want to achieve it via regex as alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\4` refers to a character whose ordinal number is octal `4` rather than a literal backslash followed by a `4`. You should use a raw string literal for the variable `a` instead:

```
a = r"SCSI\DISK&VEN_MICRON&PROD_1100\4&2096297&0&000200"
```

Also, instead of using `r"\4&2096297&0+"` as your regex, you should use double backslashes to denote a literal backslash so that `\4` would not be interpreted as a backreference:

```
r"\\4&2096297&0+"
```

And finally, instead of `re.match`, you should use `re.search` since `re.match` matches the regex from the beginning of the string, which is not what you want.

So:

```
 import re
 a = r"SCSI\DISK&VEN_MICRON&PROD_1100\4&2096297&0&000200"
 print(bool(re.search(r"\\4&2096297&0+", a)))
```

would output: `True`

Comment: this raises an error `sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\4'`

Comment: It works for me. Please post your actual code if it doesn't for you.

Comment: Now I get it, But why  `re.match` returns false but `re.search` give true.

Comment: Also, sorry if its a stupid question. But can is it possible to remove that raw string literal from `a`. Because I get those value from a server can't expliciltly convert them to a raw string

Comment: The raw string literal is only used here so that we can hard-code it for a discussion here. If you obtain the string from a server then there is no need for a conversion at all since it is already stored with such a value.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import re

    pattern = "\4&2096297&0"
    print(bool(re.search(pattern,a)))   # this would print "True"
```

Comment: this prints false

Comment: For me , it prints "True" . Please check whether you have typed the "pattern" variable correctly